# Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. with re-seller hosting

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, git-remote

I'm trying to setup githook in my reseller hosting account (inmotion hosting). I have setup folder for git with `git init --bare` and configured `post-receive` file and added remote ssh in git.When i run  `git remote -v`

```
origin  https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}.git (push)
production      ssh://{hostingusername}@{domain-name}:{port}/repo/site.git (fetch)
production      ssh://{hostingusername}@{domain-name}:{port}/repo/site.git (push)
```

I'm getting error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

while trying running

```
git push production master
```

Comment: Did you upload your public key to the server? If you authenticate using passwords, is that enabled on the server?

Comment: Upload public key from git into hosting server  ?

Comment: Have you added your Public Key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) in your GitHub Account (production repo)?

Comment: i added my git public key in my hosting ssh and authorized it. Now i'm getting `fatal: '/repo/site.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` error

Comment: @sajibkhan i can see all `id_rsa.pub`  and other files with `ls -al ~/.ssh` in git bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your directory path if you are using shared hosting. I have doubt in that. I also had same kind of trouble way back.

Comment: Thanks for reminding that. I did made a mistake on my directory path. it should be `home/{username}/repo/site,git`